# How to set the window to sleep on WPF?

Tags: wpf, window, sleep, effect

How to get the window to sleep mode when the Winter Sleep button is pressed with the controls in the picture like the screen.
We can also give the window an effect like this (with the effect of aero glass but I haven't found this effect in research).
`Kış Uykusu = Winter Sleep`

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MWYW6di2gwtbDJPqNZsDlUysG-1PDSG5)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o1YU.gif)

Comment: Hi Mustafa, your question is too broad to answer. In order to help you, please write what you already tried to accomplish your goal and provide some code.

Comment: Please go through [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section and improve your question. That could help someone to understand your question easily.

Comment: it was difficult to explain with words.